# how to index a field that holds a subdocument?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

schema:

{
A: {
X: "string",
Y: "string",
Z: "string"
}
}

Is it possible to index `A` and have this index used when querying for `A.X`, `A.Y`, or `A.Z`?

Comment: Have you checked out [wildcard index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/indexes/index-types/index-wildcard/reference/embedded-object-behavior/#wildcard-indexes-on-embedded-objects)?